# Как обрезать изображение в CarrierWave?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gems

Речь о геме CarrierWave, а если быть точнее, то о MiniMagick.

Как обрезать изображение при загрузке?

Например, оригинал изображение 1920x1080. Загружаем на сервер оригинал (1920x1080), его миниатюру(900x506), а также необходимо загрузить его обрезанную версию (900x200).

Вот проблема возникает только с обрезанием. Ресайзить проблем нет.

Comment: Ну, после обрезки могут остаться разные регионы. Вы заранее выбираете за всех или это должен выбрать загружающий?

Comment: @D-side это как альтернативное изображение. Для всех загружаемых изображений.

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос, по какому принципу будет выбрана отрезаемая область.

Comment: @Colibri http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448032/unable-to-crop-image-using-mini-magick

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй гем [CarrierWave-Crop](https://github.com/kirtithorat/carrierwave-crop), если недостаточно родной инструкции, есть хорош видео-туториал https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltoPZEzmtJA